# Unable to solve "ORA-28759: failure to open file" when trying to access https websites from plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

- ACL Settings are taken care of.
- Certifications are saved in wallet.
- Tried everything. Nowhere proper solution is given.

Kindly help.

```
Below is the procedure:

create or replace procedure p_test_https as 
    v_url               VARCHAR2(50) := 'https://support.oracle.com/';
    v_http_req          UTL_HTTP.req;
    v_http_resp         UTL_HTTP.resp;  
BEGIN 
    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET ('file:D:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\owm\wallets\GaneshY','test1234');   
    v_http_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(v_url);
    v_http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(v_http_req);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_http_resp.status_code);
    UTL_HTTP.end_response(v_http_resp);
END p_test_https;
/

Test block:
begin
p_test_https;
end ;
/

Error:
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-28759: failure to open file
ORA-06512: at "DEV58.P_TEST_HTTPS", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Is your Oracle database allowed to write to any directory? It looks like it can't read in `D:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\owm\wallets\GaneshY`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697841/oracle-error-ora-28759-failure-to-open-file-when-requesting-utl-http-package