# ORA-2973 HTTP request failed, ORA-28759 failure to open file

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, get

I am using the GET API for https:abc.io/api/connectivity. For achieving this target I had add the certificate and create the Oracle wallet and also created the ACL, but when I execute my procedure it gives me:

> ORA-2973 HTTP request failed, ORA-28759 failure to open file error.

As I also grant the privileges to the user to utl.http.

```
create or replace function GET_API_DATA
  return varchar2 is
  s_entire_msg clob;
  s_msg        varchar2(80);
  s_url        varchar2(32000);
  s_req        utl_http.req;
  s_resp       utl_http.resp;
  f_result     varchar2(32000);
  v_result     varchar2(20000);
begin


  s_url  := 'https://api.uat/api/connectivity';
  UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:c:\wallet', 'Oracle_1234');
  s_req  := utl_http.begin_request(s_url,'GET',null, null, 'ap-hostname');
  s_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => s_req);

  BEGIN
    LOOP
      utl_http.read_text(r => s_resp, data => s_msg);
      s_entire_msg := s_entire_msg || s_msg;
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    when utl_http.end_of_body THEN
      utl_http.end_response(s_resp);
    WHEN others THEN
      utl_tcp.close_all_connections;
  END;

  apex_json.parse(s_entire_msg);
  v_result := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'status');
  f_result := v_result;

  return f_result;

EXCEPTION
  when no_data_found then
    null;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Is c:\wallet a directory on the database server, readable for the oracle os-user, and does it contain the file that has the certificate(s)?

Comment: Yes directory is created on database server, and i had given privileges to ora_dba as given in the below article [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697841/oracle-error-ora-28759-failure-to-open-file-when-requesting-utl-http-package]